# How to disconect a client but keep the socket, WINAPI, sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, winapi

I making a server/client chat program in C using the winapi for sockets. In that I have a part of the code that test for a specific input from the client, *like* a password, and if the input is wrong I want to **disconect** the client and **prepare to accept another conection**.
The thing that is bothering me is should I use `shutdown()` or `close()`? And from where should I jump back to wait for another connection? This is a example code:

```c
// Preparing socket with WSAStartup(), getaddrinfo(), socket(), bind() and freeaddrinfo()

conec_again:

    if (listen(sockServ, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "listen() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
        closesocket(sockServ);
        WSACleanup();
        return 5;
    }

    if ((sock = accept(sockServ, 0, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "accept() failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
        closesocket(sockServ);
        WSACleanup();
        return 6;
    }

    recv(sock, Resposta, BUFTAM, 0);
    if (CompMat(Resposta, test_mat, BUFTAM)) // My implementation to compare matrices
    {
        std::cout << "Trying again.\n";  // Placeholder text
        goto conec_again;
    }

// Stuff...
```

Yes, this is done in C++, as you can see the use of std::cout, but this is just temporary and I will do most stuff in C.

How should I disconect the client and is this `goto` part corect to wait for another client?

Comment: You do the listen exactly once.  Then you accept for each connection and when you are done you can close it and jump back to the accept.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question. Re your title, this is impossible: a disconnected TCP socket cannot be re-used. Re your question, you must use `close()`. You can call `shutdown()` as well if you know why you're doing it, but you must use `close()` regardless. You aren't storing the resullt of `recv()`, and you aren't error-checking it. You can't seriously be proposing to write a `goto` in this day and age, 60 years after they were identified as harmful. Use a `while` loop and `continue`. Don't write code like this. You need to have a good look at a decent networking tutorial.

Comment: @user207421 "*a disconnected TCP socket cannot be re-used*" - Actually, on Windows it can, but only if you use `DisconnectEx()` with the `TF_REUSE_SOCKET` flag, and then `AcceptEx()` (or `ConnectEx()`) to reuse it

Comment: @RemyLebeau Blimey. Whatever will those people think of next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I disconect the client

By closing (`closesocket()`) the connected socket.

> and is this goto part corect to wait for another client?

You should not `listen()` again, but instead just go back to `accept()` another connection.  But don't use `goto` for that.  Contrary to some advice and opinion you may see, `goto` *does* have the occasional good use in C, but this is not one of them.  Use a loop.

Comment: Note, on Windows, it is `closesocket()` not `close()`

Comment: I use `goto` because the main program will go inside of a while true and I cant place a while that cut the other while in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, @EnderMega, I don't follow that.  If you are using `goto` to jump into the body of a loop then that's horrible.  If you're jumping from one place inside a loop to another, then you can absolutely use a nested loop.  You may, however, find that it makes things easier and clearer to factor some of the work out into separate functions.

Comment: I mean jumping **out** of a loop.

Comment: What you said worked, just one more question: Does `closesocket()` make so I cant just accept another client? Or I can `closesocket()` and wait in with the `accept()` for another client?

Comment: @EnderMega, the listening socket, with which you accept connections, is separate from the connected sockets with which you communicate with other machines.  They can each be closed without affecting the other(s).  Closing the connected socket does not interfere with accepting more connections via the listening socket.  Closing the listening socket would prevent accepting any additional connections with it, but would not disconnect the existing connected sockets.